# Why aren't my tableview rows populating with my provided data?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Every row in my table view just says "Table View Cell". I've inspected my data source array that I'm using and it has 55 objects, none of which have the value of "Table View Cell".

```
@implementation BMAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
      self.schemes = [BMSchemeHandler parseSchemeFileToArray];
    self.schemeTableView.dataSource=self;
    self.schemeTableView.delegate=self;

}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    return [self.schemes objectAtIndex:row];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
    return (self.schemes.count);
}
```

[image]

Here is my solution...

```
@implementation BMAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
      self.schemes = [BMSchemeHandler parseSchemeFileToArray];
    self.schemeTableView.dataSource=self;
    self.schemeTableView.delegate=self;

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
    return (self.schemes.count);
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
   viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                  row:(NSInteger)row {

    // Retrieve to get the @"MyView" from the pool or,
    // if no version is available in the pool, load the Interface Builder version
    if([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"myCell"]){
    NSTableCellView* result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"myCell" owner:self];

    // Set the stringValue of the cell's text field to the nameArray value at row
    result.textField.stringValue = [self.schemes objectAtIndex:row];

    // Return the result
    return result;
    }else{

    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at Apple's tableview playground or something similar, what you're missing is a binding in the table cell's text field.  In the XIB, in the table cell, they bind the value of the text field to the table view with a key path of objectValue.[NSString property] -- you are telling the table view what the object value is, so you could depend on that binding.

If you don't bind the text field in the cell to the object that you are returning in objectValueForTableColumn:row:, then you need to implement the NSTableViewDelegate protocol and implement TableView:viewForTableColumn:row to dequeue a cellview and get a pointer to the text field to set its string value.

Just setting the object value is insufficient.  The NSTableCellView needs to know where the text is coming from in that object.